# Is it possible to store a image on to a different location other then the appdata folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
public string AsyncUpload()
{
    return _fileStore.SaveUploadedFile(Request.Files[0]);
}
```

in the SaveUpload

```
 private string _uploadsOriginalFolder = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/Images/OriginalImages");
 private string _uploadsThumbnailFolder =  HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/Images/Thumbnails");

var identifier = Guid.NewGuid();
var originalFileNameToSave = identifier.ToString() +".jpg" ;
fileBase.SaveAs( Path.Combine(_uploadsOriginalFolder, originalFileNameToSave));
imagingService.ResizeImage(Path.Combine(_uploadsOriginalFolder, originalFileNameToSave),
Path.Combine(_uploadsThumbnailFolder,originalFileNameToSave),
160,
120,
false);
return originalFileNameToSave;
```

I want to have Domain.Com/Thumbnails/guid.jpg and Domain/OriginalImages/guid.jpg

i want this to be stored on to a \dfs.domain.com\Scanning[project]\Images directory.

how do i save it to that location and what rights do i need to provide on it.

has any body done this before. i guess many?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the image wherever you want on your server as long as you provide write permissions to that folder. Obviously if you want to access it from another ASP.NET application you can no longer use relative paths. So if the `dfs.domain.com` site root is physically mapped to`c:\foobar` you could save the file as absolute path at `c:\foobar\Scanning[project]\Images` folder. The MVC application that is saving the file has no way of knowing how is this other site configured so you could externalize the other site root path at your `web.config`.

Answer (score 0):

The best is to map phisical path to virtual folder in iis, and then allow write permisson on it.  This is how I done when I have multiple web apps, which are using same folder for static content.